# vijava get list of user names or accounts in virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, user-accounts, vsphere

I am using the beta of VI Java API 5.5 that was just released to support vSphere 5.5. My goal is to retrieve all of the existing local and domain accounts (or user names) that reside in a virtual machine. If the domain accounts cannot be retrieve, then I'd like to at least get the local accounts in the virtual machine.

I've looked throughout vijava api and cannot find anything that can perform such operation. I can verify if an account exists by providing the user name and password to validate the account, but I don't want to do that.

Does any one have any ideas on how this can be achieved, if possible?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

What I know is only [GuestInfo](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.vm.GuestInfo.html) has the details about the guest OS. Which you can get by

```
GuestInfo guest = vm.getGuest();
System.out.println("User: "+ guest.hostName);
```

More than this may be achievable by login inside guest using `NamePasswordAuthentication` and run native OS command using `StartProgramInGuest` . Store the user names in a file and later download the file.

Comment: Hey Reuben, thanks for the reply. I explored this option, however, I don't want to have the need to provide a user name and password for that VM. I was hoping to get the info using VMware Tools without the need of providing credentials to log in to the VM. It seems that this may not be possible and that it can only be achieved by providing log in credentials and executing a native OS command as you stated. Thanks though!